# Proving a sequence converges without finding limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just asking a quick question about converging sequences. We were told to prove the sequence below converges and then find the limit:

$a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n + \cos(2^n)}{n^2}$

We were told that we can't use the $\epsilon-N$ definiton, so I assume that we have to use the squeeze theorem but I am strugging to see how to use that to prove that the series converges without actually finding the limit.

If someone could just give me a hint where to start I should be able to go from there.

Comment: Well it is clear that the sequence converges since the numerator is bounded while the denominator increases to infinity.

Comment: I read that somewhere but we haven't covered that yet in class so I assume we cant use that to prove it.

Comment: You can bound it by the sequence $b_n = \frac{2}{n^2}$, which we know converges.